# Linear Search Array String

Tags: java, arrays, linear-search

I need to find a string element in my array but when I check to see, it always comes up as found, even if its not the case. I am trying to call a method.

```
    String name = "";
    boolean result = false;




   if (option == 5)
            {
        System.out.println("Please enter a students name");
        name = input.next();

        linearSearch(student);


        if (result = true)
        {System.out.println(name+" found in element ");}

        else
        {System.out.println(name+" not found in element ");}


    }


public static boolean linearSearch(String b[])
{
String key = null;
boolean searchReturn = false;
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
    //if key is found - return position of key i.e. n
    if( b[i] == key)
    searchReturn = true;
}

return searchReturn;
```

Comment: ``if(result = true)`` should be ``if(result == true)`` or simply ``if(result)``.

Comment: String comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/335858

Comment: And a third bug, you're not actually using the given `name`, instead you always compare with `key` which is `null`.

Comment: `if (result = true)`: pay attention to any warning messages output by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

String equality should be checked with String.equals(str) method.

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
     {
        //if key is found - return position of key i.e. n
        if( b[i].equals(name))
        searchReturn = true;
    }
```

Comment: when I do it this way, it is coming back as not being found, even if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should call `if(result == true){} //you performing a assignment.`

Comment: also where did the student variable came from?

Comment: Its the name of my string array, im calling my method into the if statement